# mysql combine two selects?

Tags: mysql

The first select is

```
select user_id, count(*) as count
from users
where referrer IS NOT NULL
group by referrer
order by count DESC
```

Then based off the records returned by that query I need to get the date for the user who referred the users in the above query.

```
select user_id from users where token = IDS_FROM_LAST_QUERY
```

I know I could use a sub query and say where IN (subquery) but I'm getting tripped up trying to keep the count from the subquery.

So in the end I need the following info

```
user_id, count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.user_id user_id, count(*) count
from users o
join users i on o.token = i.user_id
where i.referrer is not null
group by referrer
order by count desc
```

Comment: I modified the join as o.token = i.referrer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CTE (common table expression).  CTE is super handy to look to get one population and then query the same or slightly different population from the CTE.

```
WITH Referrer (user_id, count) AS
(
select user_id, count(*) as count
from users
where referrer IS NOT NULL
group by referrer
order by count DESC
)

select 

users.user_id
,Referrer.count

from users 

inner join Referrer.user_id = users.user_id
```